# Sum the filesizes in a directory

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to accomplish this. I'm relatively new to working with monads/IO, so excuse me if I'm missing something obvious. I searched google for a while and came up with nothing, and nothing I've read is making me figure out how to do this.

Here is what I have now:

```
import System.Path.Glob (glob)
import System.Posix.Files (fileSize, getFileStatus)

dir = "/usr/bin/"
lof = do files <- (glob (dir++"*"))
         (mapM_ fileS files)

fileS file = do fs <- getFileStatus file
                print (fileSize fs)
```

As you can see, this gets the sizes and prints them out, but I'm stuck on how to actually sum them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're almost there.  You can have `fileS` return the file size instead of printing it:

```
return (fileSize fs)
```

Then, instead of `mapM_`ing (which throws away the result), do a `mapM` (which returns the list of results):

```
sizes <- mapM fileS files
```

Now `sizes` is a list of numbers corresponding to the sizes.  `sum`ming them should be easy :-)

To deepen your understanding of this example (and practice good habits), try to write type signatures for your functions.  Consult ghci with `:t` for help.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out now. Works like a charm :)